# Dynamic content generation using JQuery Mobile UI

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

Am trying to create a mobile compatible page. Its a wizard which populates a Question(Text) & it s drop down list of Answers. Based on the answer selection from the dropdown, it will again come up with another relevant Q and A. This continues, till the wizard finds the right result for the user.

I am creating a dynamic div and appending the Text and List options to it.
Am making ajax calls to fetch the result from server side,by passing the answer & question IDs (Restful Webservice).
Am new to JQuery/JQuery Mobile world. Currently, stuck on how to proceed looping the ajax call till the final Question is reached.
Appreciate any help on this topic, if the approach is correct?

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div data-role="content" id="page_1">
      <h1>Question</h1>
      <input type="button" id="click" name="click" value="Click" /> 
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#click").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://FirstWebserviceURL',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                //To get the first Q and A
                $.each(data, function (arrayID, group) {
                    $("#page_1").append(group.quesText);
                    var s = $("<select id=\"selectId\" name=\"selectName\" />");
                    $.each(group.lstAnswerOptions, function (innerID, arr) {
                        $('<option value="' + arr.value + '" class="dropDownBlk">' + arr.label + '</option>').appendTo(s);
                    });
                    s.appendTo("#page_1");
                });

                //Stuck here, on how to loop the ajax call          
                $('#selectId').on("change", function () {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        val = $this.val();
                    $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'http://SecondWSURLwithQ&AnsID',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data_1) {
                            $.each(data_1, function (arrayID_1, group_1) {
                                $("#page_1").append(group_1.quesText);
                                var s_1 = $("<select id=\"selectId\" name=\"selectName\" />");
                                $.each(group_1.lstAnswerOptions, function (innerID_1, arr_1) {
                                    $('<option value="' + arr_1.value + '" class="dropDownBlk">' + arr_1.label + '</option>').appendTo(s_1);

                                });

                                s_1.appendTo("#page_1");
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            },
            error: function (errObj, status, error) {
                alert("error: " + errObj + " - " + status + " - " + error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please add relevant code.

Comment: Aren't you able to create a selectmenu? Is that the problem?

Comment: Am able to create the select menu. It creates first Q &A, and based on the answer selected, it appends the 2nd Q & A to the div (id =page_1) Need some help on how I can proceed with the onchange of 2nd ans option selected.